# How to call REST service in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I need to call simle rest client https://httpbin.org/ip and paste JSON result into label field in iOS device.
I'm writing in XCode 8.0, and the Swift version is 3.0.
I found many tutorials, but all of them are written for older versions of Swift. Compiler is failing and I cannot fix it. It seems that newer version have significant changes.
Can anyone please provide a working example. Will be appreciated a lot. Thanks.

In the example I am expecting to see the REST invocation and reading the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it works well.

```
   @IBOutlet weak var ipLabel: UILabel!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         let parseData = parseJSON(getJSON("https://httpbin.org/ip"))
         let ipvalue = parseData.valueForKey("origin")
         self.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(ViewController.updateIPlbl(_:)), withObject: ipvalue, waitUntilDone: false)
        }

    func getJSON(urlToRequest:String) -> NSData
        {
            return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
        }

    func parseJSON(inputData:NSData) -> NSDictionary{
            let dictData = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: .MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
            return dictData
        }

    func updateIPlbl(text: String) {
            self.ipLabel.text = "Your IP is " + text
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But XCode asked me to slightly change syntax almost in every function you provided. Could you please explain why your version was not compiling successfully? My code is the following
For example: func getJSON(urlToRequest:String) -> NSData
    {
        return NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)! as URL)!
    }